# swift floating button on UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, floating-action-button

I have a Tab Bar Controller with 3 section. I've created also a floating button for special functions but, now It's on only one section. I would like to add this button once and to show it in all section. So you can use this button through all App.

Is it possible?

An idea could be add this button to UITabBarController. Is It possible? Have you any idea?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/SUITabView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Swift 4**

You need subclass TabBarController e manipulate it.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
let btn = UIButton() //Here create your button

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Here set up your button

    self.view.insertSubview(btn, belowSubview: self.tabBar) //<--This is important. 
   //With this call you have a button that is over all view but under the tab bar. 
   //So if you have a round button that it expanded on click, the expanded 
   //part could be hidden by the tab bar, if it is near to tab bar.


   //Other button's setting if you need

    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //<- Important
   //Because you are adding the button programmatically you need set the
   //constraints. to do it, you need set to false the autoresizing mask.

    //Here set the constraints.
    //These constraints put the button in the lower right corner, over the tab bar
    let viewDictionary = ["button":btn, "tabBar":self.tabBar]
    let btn_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[button(340)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)
    let btn_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[button(340)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)
    let btn_POS_V = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[button]-(-130)-[tabBar]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)
    let btn_POS_H = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[button]-(-129)-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)

    btn.addConstraints(btn_V)
    btn.addConstraints(btn_H)
    self.view.addConstraints(btn_POS_H)
    self.view.addConstraints(btn_POS_V)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/ 

}
```

This is the results
[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

[image: Button closed]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to the app's window

```
let del = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

del.window?.addSubview(btn)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way for Storyboard? Or Is it possible only programmatically?

Comment: I've try your code but don't work. you don't see the button because it's is under the viewController contained by tab bar. Any suggestion?